# How do I get package-specific settings?

Tags: laravel, administrator

I am using the "administrator" package with Laravel 4 and I found that the settings are stored in "app/storage/administrator_settings/site.json". Now how do I get the data from this file so that I can use it in my controller and views.

Comment: Is it this package : https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator/ ? I guess you have to open an issue on their github or look yourself into the code. Saving config as json is, as far as I know, not a built in of laravel but a package specific saving method

Comment: Thank you for your reply @edi9999. That's the package I am using. I have posted an issue in github hope they will reply soon.